# Flip Board type Detail View Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I would like to do a flipboard detail view type animation (when user taps on showing elements and it shows the detail view with animation).
I am having a list of records displaying in uitableview, so for show detail view I would like to implement FlipBoard Detail view type Animation.
If someone had tried this type of animation. Please help me. So far I tried different different View Transition/Animation But did not get the desired out put.

For now I am using this code for animation but did not work as desired output

//in tableview didselected index:

```
if([arrPostsData count]>0)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kShowWaitAlert object:nil];
    detailvwScrollCount = indexPath.row; 

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

    detailVwBg.alpha = 0.0;
    detailVwBg.alpha = 1.0;
    btnBack.alpha = 1;

    [self showPostDetail:arrPostsData tapedCell:detailvwScrollCount PostedFiles:arrUserPostedFilesDataDic comments:arrCommentsDataDic];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:detailVwBg];
    isDetailvwActive = TRUE;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This simply shows detail view with other type animation, while i am trying for display detail like: increasing motion from corner till to top screen.
For example: I taped on the last visible cell of the tableview so now that cell should be increase from till to top screen and finally it will be like full screen detail view that show all detail of the taped row.

Please help..

Thank You

Comment: I tried so far different different View Transition Animation provide by IOS SDK.. but it did not get the desired output from them.

Comment: show some code so that we can help you...but do not ask this kind of questions to provide all the data from the stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController=[[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *animateView = self.navigationController.view;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:animateView cache:YES];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Nuzhat: Thanks for your post but it did not working like the one I want to implement (Flipboard  detail View animation effect).